# "invalid value" when calling gluNewQuadric

Tags: c, opengl

When I run this code, the console shows "invalid value" as error. I researched in my books but did not find how to solve it. They don't even mention what this value is about. I imagine that it would be address number stored in the pointer returned by `gluNewQuadric` that can be out of range of the type GLUquadric, but have no way to make sure or either fix it

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <GL/glut.h>

#ifndef CALLBACK
#define CALLBACK
#endif

void CALLBACK erro(GLenum coderro)
{
    const GLubyte *estring;
    estring=gluErrorString(coderro);
    fprintf(stderr, "Erro de quadrica: %s\n", estring);
    exit(0);
}


void tela ()
{
    GLUquadric *quadrica;
    glClearColor(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glOrtho(-30.0, 30.0, -30.0, 30.0, 1, 100);

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glTranslated(0.0, 0.0, -20.0);

    glColor3f(1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    quadrica=gluNewQuadric();
    gluQuadricCallback(quadrica, GLU_ERROR, erro);
    gluQuadricDrawStyle(quadrica, GLU_FILL);
    gluDisk(quadrica, 0.0, 5.0, 1, 1);

    glFlush();
}

int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode( GLUT_SINGLE | GLUT_RGB );
    glutInitWindowSize(500, 500);
    glutCreateWindow("Tesselacao");
    glutDisplayFunc(tela);
    glutMainLoop();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the specification of [`gluDisk`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/gluDisk.xml):

> ```
>  void gluDisk(    GLUquadric* quad,
>      GLdouble inner,
>      GLdouble outer,
>      GLint slices,
>      GLint loops);
> ```
>
> Parameters
>   [...]
>   `slices` Specifies the number of subdivisions around the z axis.

This means `slices` has to be at least 3, because to generate a shape, at least 3 points around the disk are necessary.

e.g.

`gluDisk(quadrica, 0.0, 5.0, 3, 1);` will generate a triangle and
`gluDisk(quadrica, 0.0, 5.0, 5, 1);` will generate a pentagon.

Answer (score 0):

If you run this in a debugger and set a breakpoint at `erro`, you'll find something like this (output from GDB):

```
Breakpoint 1, erro (coderro=100901) at test.c:12
12          estring=gluErrorString(coderro);
(gdb) bt
#0  erro (coderro=100901) at test.c:12
#1  0xf7dd7782 in gluQuadricError (qobj=0x81ddb70, which=100901) at src/libutil/quad.c:81
#2  0xf7dd85ad in gluPartialDisk (qobj=0x81ddb70, innerRadius=0, outerRadius=5, slices=1, loops=1, startAngle=0, sweepAngle=360) at src/libutil/quad.c:450
#3  0xf7dd84c8 in gluDisk (qobj=0x81ddb70, innerRadius=0, outerRadius=5, slices=1, loops=1) at src/libutil/quad.c:427
#4  0x08048af2 in tela () at test.c:36
#5  0xf7f72da8 in fghRedrawWindow () from /usr/lib/libglut.so.3
#6  0xf7f72df3 in fghcbDisplayWindow () from /usr/lib/libglut.so.3
#7  0xf7f77a90 in fgEnumWindows () from /usr/lib/libglut.so.3
#8  0xf7f72e47 in fghDisplayAll () from /usr/lib/libglut.so.3
#9  0xf7f73f39 in glutMainLoopEvent () from /usr/lib/libglut.so.3
#10 0xf7f73f97 in glutMainLoop () from /usr/lib/libglut.so.3
#11 0x08048b52 in main (argc=1, argv=0xffffd4e4) at test.c:48
```

So, the error comes from `gluDisk`. Now a simple attempt to play with its parameters lets me guess that the culprit is `slices=1`, which indeed doesn't make sense. Setting it to e.g. `2` avoids getting into the error callback.